# Cannot get api information via retrofit2 in android app using token

Tags: android, laravel, retrofit2

I have this routes in my api.php in laravel:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function() {
Route::get("students/{id}",[StudentController::class, 'showStudentJson'])->name('students.showStudentJson');
    
});
```

If I make this get request using postman like this: http://127.0.0.1/api/students/42 and in the authorization section I add a bearer token with the right token I get the right information.

The problem is that I don´t know how to make the request from the android app using the token.

I have the following apiservice:

```
@GET("api/students/{id}")
    Call<Alumno> getStudent(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Path("id") int id);
```

And when I make the call I do it like this:

```
ApiService service= Api.getApi(getApplicationContext()).create(ApiService.class);

Call<Alumno> alumnoCall=service.getStudent(sessionManager.fetchAuthToken(),id);

alumnoCall.enqueue(new Callback<Alumno>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Alumno> call, Response<Alumno> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Alumno alumno=response.body();
                   /*Toast.makeText(MenuPrincipal.this, "El servidor retornó datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                    tv1.setText("Bienvenido "+alumno.getName());

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MenuPrincipal.this, "El servidor retornó un error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Alumno> call, Throwable t) {
                if(t instanceof IOException){
                    Toast.makeText(MenuPrincipal.this, "Error de conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MenuPrincipal.this, "Problema de conversión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

`sessionManager.fetchAuthToken()` returns the token.

If I make the call without the token and I take the route in laravel out of the sanctum middleware it works, but if I do it with the token it doesn´t. I know it has something to do with the way I add the token to the call but I don´t know how to fix it.

Any idea?
Thank you.